# Why was my question deleted without any reason?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

My question was removed some 20 minutes after it was posted. Why did this happen? My question was perfectly valid. A copy is provided below. Kindly repost it, please!

> What are some technical tasks to convert powerpoint to flash and import it online to a web app?
>
> Example Use case
> http://www.sliderocket.com
> Sliderocket is an online presentation software with presentation creation and import features
> Front End - flash (flex), Backend - asp.net, mysql

Comment: He actually did [post this as a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314207/what-are-some-technical-tasks-to-convert-powerpoint-to-flash-and-import-it-onlin)...

Comment: @animuson I know, I deleted the comment a couple of seconds after I posted it.

Comment: Its amusing you guys are talking to this spammer like he's worth anything.

Comment: There is something wrong on the Internet, @Won't, and I must fix it.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you posted [your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313605/converting-powerpoint-to-flash-and-taking-it-online) two hours ago, which read:

> What are some technical task in converting powerpoint to flash?
>   example - sliderocket.com is an online presentation vendor that
>   converts ppt to swf. Its front end - adobe flex (flash), backend -
>   msft asp.net, mysql Click (www.sliderocket.com "Sliderocket - online
>   presentation software")

This was flagged as spam, and it sure looked like it, so I closed and removed that question. You then [proceeded to ask this again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314207/what-are-some-technical-tasks-to-convert-powerpoint-to-flash-and-import-it-onlin):

> Example Use case http://www.sliderocket.com Sliderocket is an online
>   presentation software with presentation creation and import features
>   Front End - flash (flex) , Backend - asp.net, mysql

and it was once again flagged as spam, with Bill deleting this one. Please stop reposting this.

Your questions aren't questions at all, and are written in the style of ads for Sliderocket. If you don't want your questions to keep being deleted, you'll need to ask an actual question about a specific technical matter, and you'll want to avoid looking like you're promoting a specific product.

Comment: @Michael My apologies if it came across as an ad. I was trying to focus on a specific use case - lets say there is an existing web app which allows a user to create presentations online. Then an 'import' button is added to the dashboard that allows a user to import a ppt into the web app. What could be some 3-4 key tasks that this new use case could be broken into? Could you suggest ways through which I could post this question?

Comment: @NagaKarunakar: That wasn't remotely clear from your question.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, Again i apologize!I also understand that the question is broad, but trying to get some inputs into breaking the task down

Answer (score 7):

Your question was valid in the sense that it was comprehensible and contained grammatical English. It was not a good question for Stack Overflow, however. There are several problems with it:

- It is **overly broad**. The first part of your question, *"What are some technical tasks to convert powerpoint to flash"*, would take ages to answer. You're asking too much in a single question. Narrow it down. Which leads me to a second problem.
- It shows **very little effort**. We're all volunteers here. We like to help, it keeps us sharp and has other rewards. We don't, as a rule, like to feel exploited. It feels like you've dropped a big pile of work on our doorstep and said "tell me what to do".
- It is **unanswerable** as currently written. *"import it online to a web app"* That can mean just so many things. This part alone needs piles of further detail.
- It **smells like spam**. Two-thirds of your question is a description of a commercial product. It sure reads like advertising copy. Now, maybe you're not a spammer - it's not a 100% lock to me. But it sure smells like it. And that, in the end, is why a moderator deleted your question, rather than just closing it.

Comment: Yep, it reeks of spam. <Insert generic problem here> <Follow up with link to solution and product description>. I don't buy OP's feigned ignorance one bit.